# python3 reportlab code 39 adding extra character

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab, code39

Using python3 and reportlab I'm trying to generate two columns of barcodes:

```
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code39
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("barcode_example.pdf", pagesize=A4)

code_list = [
    'E100', 'RA100', 
    'E101', 'RA101', 
    'E102', 'RA102', 
    'E103', 'RA103', 
    'E104', 'RA104',
    'E105', 'RA105', 
    'E106', 'RA106', 
    'E107', 'RA107', 
    'E108', 'RA108', 
    'E109', 'RA109']
x = 1 * mm
y = 278 * mm
x1 = 6.4 * mm

for i, code in enumerate(code_list):
    barcode = code39.Extended39(code, barWidth=0.6*mm, barHeight=15*mm)

    if i % 2 == 0:
        barcode.drawOn(c, x, y)
        x1 = x + 6.4 * mm
        c.drawString(x1, y- 5 * mm, code)
    else:
        x1 = x + 100 * mm
        barcode.drawOn(c, x1, y)
        y = y - 5 * mm
        c.drawString(x1 + 6.4 * mm, y, code)
        y = y - 25 * mm


#    if int(y) == 0:
#        x = x + 50 * mm
#        y = 285 * mm

c.showPage()
c.save()
```

It generates a file and seems to be just fine but after scanning them in with a barcode scanner they read as follows:

```
E100F   RA100 
E101G   RA101$
E102H   RA102/
E103I   RA103+
E104J   RA104%
E105K   RA1050
E106L   RA1061
E107M   RA1072
E108N   RA1083
E109O   RA1094
```

RA100 has a space after it.
It is clearly going in order of ASCII precedence I just don't know why. Is there a setting I'm suppose to enable/disable?

Also, it's definitely not the barcode scanner, I reset it to read code39 and tested it on other non-reportlab generated barcodes and they worked just fine.

Thank you for your help!

Also, I modified the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179269/python-barcode-generation-library

**Edit**
When I tested with code128, it worked perfectly. So it appears to be specific to code39

**EDIT 2: And I'm an idiot. My barcode scanner doesn't support the checksum option. Disabling the checksum in reportlab fixed my issue. I'm going to leave this just in case someone else comes across this problem.**

Disable checksum via:

```
barcode = code39.Extended39(code, barWidth=0.6*mm, barHeight=15*mm, checksum=0)
```

checksum=False would probably work just fine, but after looking at their source they use 1 and 0 for true/false and figured it would be safer to adhere to their practices.

Comment: Thanks! This is the exact problem I ran into. Also implemented the same use of 0 after looking in the source.